# Safari Box-Shadow: what is interfering?

Tags: html, css, safari

I have three menus in a website that behave in a similar way, but two of them are broken in safari. I did not build this website but am currently working on upgrades, so I am hoping a fresh set of eyes will shed some light.

I will compare the working and non-working navigation menus and discuss what I have researched to this point.

(please note: this is a hover effect)

**Working Example:**

```
#main-navigation ul li a {
display: block;
text-align: center;
width: 130px;
height: 130px;
line-height: 128px;
font-size: 20px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-o-border-radius: 50%;
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
-webkit-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
-moz-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
-o-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
-ms-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
}

#main-navigation ul li a:hover {
background: #359ed6;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid #8ec9e8;
box-shadow: 0 0 40px #6db2d7;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #6db2d7;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #6db2d7;
-o-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #6db2d7;
}
```

[image: Working Example]

**Broken Example:**

```
#work .tab-strips {
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding-bottom: 58px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #275871;
padding-top: 50px;
}

#work .tab-strips li {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 -15px;
vertical-align: top;
position: relative;
}

#work ul li a {
overflow: hidden;
display: table;
text-align: center;
width: 225px;
height: 225px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
border-radius: 50%;
-ms-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-o-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
-webkit-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
-moz-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
-o-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
-ms-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0s;
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff;
line-height: 30px;
font-weight: 200;
}

#work ul li a:hover {
background: #359ed6;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid #8ec9e8;
box-shadow: 0 0 40px #6db2d7;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #6db2d7;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #6db2d7;
-o-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #38434a;
}


#work .tab-strips li a span {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}

#work .tab-strips li.active a {
border: 1px solid #223541;
color: #223541;
}
```

[image: Broken Example]

I have researched and learned that Safari only supports the unprefixed version of box-shadow starting from version 5.1 on the desktop, I have included this in `#work ul li a:hover...` so I do not believe this is the cause.

The hover effect works in all cases in Chrome, IE and Firefox.

There can be no spacing before the brackets in the transition code for Safari, this is also not the cause.

I hope that this question shows thought and that I am not simply missing something obvious. I have reviewed the *Safari Developer Library* and found no resolution.

Comment: The unprefixed version should always be last in the order. eg 
`-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #6db2d7;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #6db2d7;
-o-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #38434a;
box-shadow: 0 0 40px #6db2d7;`

Comment: They are in consistent order between the working and non-working examples. However I have made the change and no difference. I appreciate your input

Comment: 1. Can you please include the relevant HTML in your post as well? 2. What version of Safari are you testing on? The latest version for Windows is 5.1.7, but the latest OSX version is 8.0.8.

Comment: Does this only happen when the circles overlap? Looks like a hardware acceleration bug to me, but its hard to say without trying it myself.